# WAMP change phpmyadmin Port

Tags: port, wamp

I found a couple topics on how to do this here, but none of them seemed to work as WAMP has changed the structure of the files in mention.

Here is my config for phpmyadmin. I'd like it to run on a different port.

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "F:/wamp_active/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#
ServerName localhost:8088
DocumentRoot "F:/wamp_active/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

<Directory "F:/wamp_active/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 200M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 200M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Comment: Have you consulted the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen)?

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I was following the tree and methods WAMP was using, which was ServerName or port under Directory.